# css parsing failing at production

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I was building react app using webpack integration. In webpack.common.js file,

in entry path, i gave vendor.js and app.js and
this is my vendor file

```
import 'react'
import 'react-dom'

// third party libraries
import 'jquery'
import 'popper.js'
import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootswatch/dist/sketchy/bootstrap.min.css'
```

when building for production, it gets failing and error is

> JisonParserError: Parse error on line 1: 255px 25px 225px...------^
>
> Expecting end of input, "ADD", "SUB", "MUL", "DIV", got unexpected "LENGTH" at C:\reactjs\react-events-portal\vendors~vendor.css:13:90472

If i remove css bootswatch then, build is working fine. bootswatch path is correct but i dont know how it is working in dev mode not in prod build.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6004 It seems to be bootswatch bug.

Comment: Yes Maciej. You are right. When i switch to other bootswatch theme they didnt have similar kind of 225px 25px calc css in their theme. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with Sketchy theme in Botswatch.
They are working in it. https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/issues/878 .
Waiting for new a version.
BTW if you change theme it works.